# How to find the CUDA __device__ definition of a function?

Tags: cuda

I have a specific function I am trying to find the source definition for, specifically what the nvcc compiler is using.  This question is phrased to apply to any function (or symbol I suppose), which is used in a `__device__` function.  Given:

```
__device__ void Foo(){
  
  int x = round( 0.0f );
}
```

What is the standard/canonical/recommended way to find the definition for "round( float )" used by the nvcc compiler to generate device code?

Normally I use Visual Studio's F1 "Go to Definition", or search for "round" in project files, etc.  I also search the CUDA Toolkit documentation and CUDA MATH API.  In this case, I find the VS cmath definition.  But how do I determine which definition the nvcc compiler uses?

Comment: `round()` is a function from CUDA's standard math library, just like it is a standard math function in C++. The source code for CUDA's standard math library is not publicly available. You can look at disassembled code to see what it does: it's a short inlined instruction sequence.

Comment: The disassembly from code generated by CUDA 11.1 for an `sm_52` target shows: `LDG.E R0, [R2]; LOP32I.AND R4, R0.reuse, 0x80000000; LOP32I.OR R5, R4, 0x3f000000; FADD.RZ R5, R0, R5; F2F.F32.F32.TRUNC R5, R5; STG.E [R2], R5;` This indicates that `round (float a)` is implemented as `truncf (__fadd_rz (a, copysignf (0.5f, a)))`. When you use `round(0.0f)` it turns into the equivalent of `truncf (__fadd_rz (0.0f, 0.5f))` by constant propagation, i.e. you wind up with two instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the standard/canonical/recommended way to find the definition for "round( float )" used by the nvcc compiler to generate device code?

[Disassembly](https://godbolt.org/z/1oac8z). Most inbuilt functions exist as stubs in headers that are expanded into inline assembly sequences as part of a device compiler code generating pass. There is no input code to view.

Comment: I'm always learning from you.  Thanks much :)